# Is it possible to Select-String by color?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

When I run a command it produces different messages with different colors. I'd like to see only those messages that have a specific color. Is it possible in some way to filter messages by text color? I'd be happy with either a PowerShell or a cmd-based solution.

Comment: So are you saying if you wrote something like `GET-WinSystemLocale` which has the keywords in yellow, and the response comes back in white, you only want to show white text on the console?

Comment: There is nothing via cmd.exe or powershell/powershell_ise/pwsh.exe natively that allows what you are after. Color is provided by conditional statements or Write-Host -foreground color/$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor or by the cmdlet, function, etc. This is not some stored attribute you can get, without directly reading the code and looking for those and changing them. What is your use case for this. The author of a given function, cmdlet, etc., adds color to output/response for given reasons; such as errors, failures, success, etc reason. What is the use case for this? You would miss informatio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this by reading each character in the console buffer, as color is only applied as it's written to the console. You can only read the console buffer in the normal console window as well - Powershell ISE for example doesn't support `GetBufferContents()`.

Here's an example function:

```
# Return text from window where foreground color is green
function Get-GreenText {
    $bufferWidth = $host.ui.rawui.BufferSize.Width
    $bufferHeight = $host.ui.rawui.CursorPosition.Y
    $rec = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle 0,0,($bufferWidth – 1),$bufferHeight
    $buffer = $host.ui.rawui.GetBufferContents($rec)

    ($buffer | 
        where ForegroundColor -like 'Green' | 
        Select -ExpandProperty Character
    ) -join ''
}
```

With this, we can capture green colored text as far up as you can scroll within the powershell window:

```
PS C:\> Write-Host 'This is default'
PS C:\> Write-Host 'This is Green' -ForegroundColor Green
PS C:\> Write-Host 'This is Magenta' -ForegroundColor Magenta
This is default
This is Green
This is Magenta
PS C:\> Get-GreenText
this is green
```

For more information, see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/capture-console-screen/